# How to show $\left(\hat{f*g}\right)_n=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat f_n\hat g_n$

Tags: fourier-transform

> How to show $\left(\hat{f*g}\right)_n=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat f_n\hat g_n$

By Definition Fourier transform of $f$ is $\displaystyle \hat f_n=\int_0^1f(y)e^{-2\pi i n y}dy$

On the left I have the Fourier transform of the convolution, i.e.

$\displaystyle \left(\hat{f*g}\right)_n=\int_0^1\int_0^1f(y)g(x-y)e^{-2\pi i n x}dydx=\int_0^1f(y)\hat g_ne^{-2\pi in y }dy$

I know that $\int_0^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx=\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\hat f_n \overline{\hat g_n}$

and also using the property $\overline{\hat g_n}=\hat g_{-n}$ I have to show that

$\hat{\left(\hat g_n e^{-2\pi n y }\right)}=g(-y)$

am I correct ? or do I make the problem more confusing ?

Comment: @Some guy you mean $\left(\hat{f*g}\right)=\hat f \hat g$ ?

Answer (score 2):

First, your formula is wrong. $f*g(x)=\int_0^1 f(y)g(x-y)\,dy,$
so the $n$-th Fourier coefficient of the convolution is $\int_0^1\int_0^1f(y)g(x-y)e^{-2\pi i n x}dydx$. Once you correct that 
it's just a little trick:

$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f(y)g(x-y)e^{-2\pi i n x}dydx
\int_0^1\int_0^1f(y)e^{-2\pi i n y}g(x-y)e^{-2\pi i n (x-y)}dydx\dots$$

Comment: C. Ulrich Of course $x$ instead of $y$ in the exponent but the rest should be OK and Yes i know the transform of the convolution gives the product of the transforms but I don't know if this is useful

Comment: @halvet Well, I just noticed that what you say you're trying to prove is also nonsense. You want to show $\widehat{f*g}(n)=\sum_n\hat f(n)\hat g(n)$? That's not so. What's true is $\widehat{f*g}(n)=\hat f(n)\hat g(n)$. You say you know that. Then what is it you're asking?

Comment: So the exercise 3 (v) is wrong here http://www.math.uzh.ch/index.php?file&key1=40906

Comment: @halvet Yes. It's _obviously_ wrong! The left side depends on $n$ but the right side does not.